# For prototype ajax what is the equilvent of using context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype

With jquery you can access `this` inside an ajax request like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/some_api/",
    context: this,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) 
    {
       //can access this inside now
    }
```

What would the equivalent be for prototype for the following call?

```
new Ajax.Request(url, 
{
    onSuccess: function(data)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use bind():

```
new Ajax.Request(url, 
{
    onSuccess: (function(data)
    {

    }).bind(this)
})
```

this will cause *this* inside the callback to be whatever *this* was outside the callback. you can also bind to objects aside from *this* to get a custom *this* object in your callback.

Comment: Excellent! I will try this tomorrow when I get to work tomorrow, this does seem like the correct way of doing it in prototype. Will accept once I test it.

Comment: keep in mind that you can bind about any function, not just callbacks in Prototype. this includes jQuery ajax callbacks...